# Highcharts BarRange with multiple points marked within the range?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been tasked with generating charts that would display a BarRange and list additional points in the range.  I've been looking at the examples for Highcharts, and like the inverted ColumnRange they show here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Temperature variation by month'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Observed in Vik i Sogn, Norway, 2009'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature ( °C )'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y + '°C';
                }
            }
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        data: [
            [-9.7, 9.4],
            [-8.7, 6.5],
            [-3.5, 9.4],
            [-1.4, 19.9],
            [0.0, 22.6],
            [2.9, 29.5],
            [9.2, 30.7],
            [7.3, 26.5],
            [4.4, 18.0],
            [-3.1, 11.4],
            [-5.2, 10.4],
            [-13.5, 9.8]
        ]
    }]

});
```

and here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2JMF/2/

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        data: [{ 
            x: 1,
            low: 7,
            high: 8,
            color: "red"
        },{
            x: 2,
            low: 6,
            high: 7,
            color: "blue"
        }]
    }]

});
```

but what I need is not just a range high/low with an x point value, I need a high/low with several other points marked (preferably as a line) within the bar.
Think about it like quartiles and average.  I want to display the range of values in my series and mark the 25th%, median, 75th% and average as line markers within the high/low bar range.

I have not been able to find any examples of marking points within a bar range.  Is this something that can be done with Highcharts?  Can you show me an example of how to achieve this?

---

**Edit:**
I've found that I can simulate what I'm after by adding additional series to the chart data.  I mocked that up by modifying the second fiddle above:

http://jsfiddle.net/tLucL6mq/1/

```
    window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        data: [{ 
            x: 1,
            low: 7,
            high: 8,
            color: "red"
        },{
            x: 2,
            low: 6,
            high: 7,
            color: "blue"
        }]
    },{
        marker: {
                fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: '#000000',
                radius: 6,
                symbol: "square"
            },
        name: "Inclusive data points",
        type: "scatter",
        data: [[2,6.25],[2,6.6],[2,6.9],[1,7.2],[1,7.6],[1,7.9]]
    },{
        marker: {
                fillColor: '#FFFF00',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: '#000000',
                radius: 5
            },
        name: "Data points with Outliers",
        type: "scatter",
        data: [[2,5.9],[2,6.4],[2,6.7],[2,7.15],[1,6.8],[1,7.5],[1,7.8],[1,8.2]]
    }
]

});
```

That looks pretty good, but I'd like to have one series that defines the range and lists points to be marked within the range.

If I have to use separate ranges like this, that's ok, but I would love the ability to mark the Inclusive data points using a line within the range rather than circle or square markers.

Comment: Could you attach mockup, how it should look like ?

Comment: I just came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231663/im-trying-to-use-highcharts-to-display-a-series-of-points-not-just-x-and-y) SO question that sounds like maybe a BoxPlot is the type of chart I need instead of a BarRange.  Going to play with that for a bit and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Unfortunately defaulty it is not build in, so you need to use two series, or develop your own serie.